# SQL Server 2012 - "Error in library(neuralnet) : there is no package called 'neuralnet'"

Tags: assembly, ssis, sql-server-2012, r.net

How can we reference external dll of R like Neuralnet from SQL Server 2012?

Currently I am trying to run a R.net assembly from SQL Server 2012. This assembly runs fine when I execute it from C#, but the problem arises when I execute it from SQL Server 2012

> Error in library(neuralnet) : there is no package called 'neuralnet'

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear of what you are asking because you have this tagged as SSIS but seem to be referencing creating an assembly in SQL Server 2012 instance.

if in SSIS script task, you have to make sure that all dependencies are installed and in global cache on the server you are executing the package on.

If you are talking about assembly in SQL Server 2012 for use as a clr(s) the issue is still dependencies, but this time there is a nuance they all have to be created as such in the database and all dependencies have to be created in order of dependence so the R assembly would be last.